# How to create user group security for REST API using middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

In order to secure REST API I'm using middleware to check for user's JWT token and only allow that particular user to access his own data.

In auth.js

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const User = require('../models/user')

const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', '')
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: decoded._id, 'tokens.token': token })

        if (!user) { // If no user is found
            throw new Error()
        }

        // if there's a user
        req.token = token
        req.user = user
        next()
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(401).send({ error: 'Please authenticate.' })
    }
}

module.exports = auth
```

In one of the get/update router

```
router.get('/itemShipmentStatus', auth, async (req, res) => {
   // Get the items shipment status from db.
})
```

However, I've noticed I need to create a new admin user (e.g. admin 1, admin2) to get and update the itemShipmentStatus for all the users. Is there a way to achieve user group authentication through the middleware (auth.js?)

**Update:**

The only solution I can think of is to add another "userGroup" field to the user document when creating a new user. Then in the middleware auth.js add in another condition to check if the user belongs to the admin group.

```
if (!user || user.userGroup !== 'Admin') { // If no user is found
    throw new Error()
}
```

Is this the conventional way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest adding `permissions` array stored in the user. That way you are more flexible.  Then

```
const auth = (allowedPermission) => (async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', '')
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: decoded._id, 'tokens.token': token })

        if (!user) { // If no user is found
            throw new Error()
        }
        if (!user.permissions.includes(allowedPermission)){
            throw new Error() // Forbidden 403
        }


        // if there's a user
        req.token = token
        req.user = user
        next()
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(401).send({ error: 'Please authenticate.' })
    }
})
```

and in the route

```
router.get('/itemShipmentStatus', auth([admin, user]), async (req, res) => {
   // Get the items shipment status from db.
})
```

Then it would be a matter to identify the correct code to run.

I would suggest considering the division of the api.  A public api and an admin api.  This is because conceptually a user may want to be admin and access its own itemShipmentStatus.  So having

```
router.get('/itemShipmentStatus', auth([admin, user]), async (req, res) => {
   // Get the items shipment status from db.
})
router.get('/admin/itemShipmentStatus', auth([admin]), async (req, res) => {
   // Get the items shipment status from db of all user.
})
```

This allows an admin user to test the API as a normal user and get all the status as an admin.

Answer (score 0):

A more conventional way of doing this would be to create an `AuthRouter` which extends the default `express.Router` and checks for allowed roles, so there will be no need to use middleware for each route.

Extending `express.Router` to check for roles:

```
const express = require('express');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/user');

export default class AuthRouter extends express.Router {
  addRoles(...roles) {
    return this.use(checkAccessForRoles(...roles));
  }
}

const checkAccessForRoles = (...roles) => async (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', '');
  const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
  const user = await User.findOne({ _id: decoded._id, 'tokens.token': token });

  if (!roles.includes(user.role)) throw new Error('Forbidden');

  req.user = user;

  return next();
};
```

Using `AuthRouter` for `ADMIN` user role:

```
const adminRouter = new AuthRouter({
  prefix: '/admin',
})
  .addRoles(['ADMIN']);

adminRouter.get('/itemShipmentStatus', async (req, res) => {
  // Get the items shipment status from db.
});
```